# Issue creating Storage Bucket in GCP using APIs

Tags: json, api, google-cloud-platform, storage, bucket

While following the Introduction to APIs in Google lab, I'm facing an issue while creating a storage bucket. I followed the instructions but still the following is shown:

Run the following command to create a Cloud Storage bucket:

curl -X POST --data-binary @values.json 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH2_TOKEN" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=$PROJECT_ID"

Error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid bucket name: '\u003cqwiklabs-gcp-00-eb5dde0a1183-bucket'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid bucket name: '\u003cqwiklabs-gcp-00-eb5dde0a1183-bucket'",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Edit your question and show how you generated the error (your code). These links should help you create good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the command that led to this error? I suggest you edit your answer and add the command you used. If you read the error, the bucket name is not a valid one, My guess is that the bucket name is not right, maybe you forgot to the `gs://` in front of it? something like `gs://u003cqwiklabs-gcp-00-eb5dde0a1183-bucket`

Comment: It was asked to create storage bucket using curl and I did as instructed still I got this error.

The following is the lab url:
https://google.qwiklabs.com/focuses/3473?parent=catalog&qlcampaign=1p-EDUCR-DSC-30DGC-STU%3A%3APSFUNKm_NtXZLtkl5PHw-g

Comment: Run the following command to create a Cloud Storage bucket:

curl -X POST --data-binary @values.json
-H "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH2_TOKEN"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=$PROJECT_ID"

Comment: Please edit your question with ALL details (values.json). Your bucket name begins with a "Control" character (\u003) which is not valid. Bucket names must contain only lowercase letters, numbers, dashes (-), underscores (_), and dots (.). Spaces are not allowed.

Comment: @Fawad it does seems like an issue with the bucket name as John Hanley mentions. Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score -1):

1.Edit the  `values.json` file

`nano values.json`

```
{  "name": "quicklab-test-your-bucket",
   "location": "us",
   "storageClass": "multi_regional"
}
```

2.Get the token:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

3.Set the variables:

```
export OAUTH2_TOKEN=your-token
export PROJECT_ID=your-project-id
```

4.Create the bucket:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @values.json \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=$PROJECT_ID"
```

5.You should receive similar output:

```
{
 "kind": "storage#bucket",
 "id": "qwiklabs-test-bucket",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/sean123456789",
 "projectNumber": "218136653205",
 "name": "sean123456789",
 "timeCreated": "2018-10-19T21:04:03.604Z",
 "updated": "2018-10-19T21:04:03.604Z",
 "metageneration": "1",
 "location": "US",
 "storageClass": "MULTI_REGIONAL",
 "etag": "CAE="
}
```